# Multiple recycler view in one fragment visible simultaneously

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

[image]
I am trying to add two recycler views to a single layout, which is in a `Fragment`. But all I can see is the first `RecyclerView`.
Is it possible to add two recycler views like in the image above (both needs to be visible at the same time), or is there some kind of limitation in android that only one recycler view can be added to one complete screen??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/test_recycle1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#FFCC00"
        android:dividerHeight="4px"
        android:background="#e0e0e0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/test_recycle2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#FFCC00"
        android:dividerHeight="4px"
        android:background="#e0e0e0"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your xml. This can be done with a LinearLayout and weights.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using too many Layout Containers like Linera Layout in one xml file, the overdraw will eventually lead to memory problems. 
Your problem can be solved by using one `LinearLayout` and by setting the height of your `RecyclerViews`  to `0dp` and the `layout_weight` to "1":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/test_recycle1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#FFCC00"
        android:dividerHeight="4px"
        android:background="#e0e0e0"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/test_recycle2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#FFCC00"
        android:dividerHeight="4px"
        android:background="#e0e0e0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you

Comment: its not working :(
when i used two recycler views on one layout with weights, the second recycler view didn't load at all. only a blank space

Comment: Do you have any data in your second RecyclerView? Did you add anything to your layout beside the two RecyclerViews?

Comment: haha :D
of course i added data to it!!!
created 2 different models as well as adapters for both, created a list, passed it to adapter, set the adapters for both the recycler view 
but only the first list loads

Answer (score 0):

Set LinearLayout weight

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/test_recycle1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#FFCC00"
            android:dividerHeight="4px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#e0e0e0"/><!---->



        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/test_recycle2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#FFCC00"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:dividerHeight="4px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#e0e0e0"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **android:weightSum** to solve your issue :

check below layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/test_recycle1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#e0e0e0"
            android:divider="#FFCC00"
            android:dividerHeight="4px" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/test_recycle2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#e0e0e0"
            android:divider="#FFCC00"
            android:dividerHeight="4px" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: nope the problem is not solved, when i used two recycler views on one layout with weights, the second recycler view didn't load at all. only a blank space